# Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls to Windows.Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printing, windows-8.1

I want to use Printing in KIOSK mode of Windows 8.1 and unfortunately it is not currently present by design.

So what I want to do is, create a Portable Class Library and add the reference to my Kiosk mode app (Windows Store app) and communicate with the default printer.

Since PrintDialog uses System.Windows.Media.Visual for printing therefore, I would like to convert Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls (Windows Store app) to Windows.Controls or Windows.Media.Visual.

Please let me know how can I achieve this conversion or is there any alternate?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a WinRT app, WPF, Silverlight???

Comment: Hey Tim, this is WinRT app.